# Unable to Install Spring Tools 4 (Spring Tool Suite 4) on Eclipse Photon - Not Compatible

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I am trying to install Spring Tool Suite in Eclipse Photon using Eclipse marketplace.

I am getting the following error when trying to install

"The following version is not compatible with version of Eclipse"

[image]

My Eclipse version is 4.8

Java version : Java 8

Eclipse Plugin link : https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-spring-boot-aka-spring-tool-suite-4

**Note:** In the market place, it was mentioned that Spring Tools 4 supports only from 4.9 and its predecessor "Spring IDE" supports only till 4.5 version.
I am using 4.8 and I am wondering how to install the spring tools

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That description of the plugin in that link only goes back to 4.9

Comment: The predecessor "Spring IDE" supports only till 4.5 version. I am using 4.8 and I am wondering how to install the spring tools

Comment: You are four releases behind. What's preventing you from [upgrading](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades)?

Comment: I would update, If I really couldn't make it work.

Comment: @NagarajaThangavelu The other way around, it would make sense: upgrade as long as nothing prevents you from doing so. Or is this about retrocomputing?

Comment: @howlger, I am using an RAD plugin in my eclipse which has supports only till 4.8. Since my entire project is developed in that RAD, I cannot update my eclipse. But possible to downgrade !!

Comment: @NagarajaThangavelu Let's talk about facts instead of about speculation. Please [upgrade your Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades) and if something is not working, simply revert the upgrade (_Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details: Install History_). Please tell, what is working and what is not working in Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12).

Answer (score 6):

Just asked the same question in Eclipse market place and following is the answer provided by the developer

Comment link : https://marketplace.eclipse.org/comment/6478#comment-6478

> The latest version of the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse require Eclipse
>   2019-03 as the base platform. If you want to instal the old Spring
>   Tool Suite 3 package instead into an Eclipse 4.8 platform, you could
>   use this update site using the "Install New Software" dialog:
>   https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.8/ - it
>   serves the STS 3.9.7 release, which is the last one compatible with
>   Eclipse 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

You should use latest version of eclipse for sts4. Good luck!!